# How to prevent command line windows from closing after errors

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

In Windows, when a Python script exits, the Command Prompt window closes.  If it exited from an error, it closes before you can read anything.  I've been using this to hold the window open even on errors:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Error:')
        print(e)
        raise
    finally:
        raw_input('(Press <Enter> to close)')
```

It works if `main()` calls `sys.exit()`, but doesn't work for things like syntax errors.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

What you have will work in most scenarios (a thread calling `os._exit()` is one notable exception).

An alternative is to wrap the Python script in a batch file, and use the [`pause`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pause.mspx?mfr=true) command after invoking the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a batch file with this code right now

```
@echo off
env\project_env\Scripts\python.exe -mpdb test.py
pause
```

`env\project_env` is a virtualenv directory with the libraries used by `test.py`

`env\project_env\Scripts\python.exe` is a python interpreter that makes the virtualenv magic to use the libraries installed in it.

`-mpdb` will open a debugger if the program terminates with an uncatched exception.